# I have changed the APN and using permission to do that, set a web client on a WebView

Tags: android, webview, proxy, apn, access-point-name

I have changed the APN and using permission to do that, set a web client on a WebView. I have also enabled JavaScript. Now I am opening the page with a URL that is opening in the browser with or without WiFi, and using the APN that I have made and set in the application. That URL does not open using the APN in the WebView till I turn on WiFi. Interestingly I have tried other APN's rather than this particular one (changing the SIM card), and there the URL is opened without a flaw.

What could be the reason a URL does not open in WebView using a particular APN only? Do I have to do some extra Web Settings?

Answer (score 0):

I had to use a function: WebView.enablePlatformNotifications();
and set permission: android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE

Thankful to my PL who guided this to me. It worked because I was using PROXY setting to access the network, and the above enabled the app to do so.